# Git remote existing distant project to local

Tags: git, drupal

**First of all, Happy New Year 2016 to all, wish you all the best !**

I have a question because so far I have not found answers from nowhere.

So here, I have an existing project made with drupal on my server online and let me know how I can clone the project locally (so a git clone brings me all project files in local), so i can make modsin local and when i do a `git push` my changes will be affect DIRECTLY on the online site.

Needless to say I've played with git init or `git init --bare` but no way, can't work it out.

Reading other tutorials, its start with a virgin repository, all users provide changes and work only in this repo (blank at the base, so it's not my case).

So The question is: How do I retrieve the project locally, edit files locally and push everything online after all this and right see the changes. Of course without going through github would be ideal but just with git.

Thank you very much for your answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I retrieve the project locally, edit files locally and push everything online after all this and right see the changes.

- Local
- remote

---

#### Locally (new project)

When you start project locally its all local ofcourse

```
    # Cd to any desired folder
    git init

    # Now you have git project

    # add the current content of your folder to the local repository
    git add .

    #commit to your local repository
    git commit -m "message"|
```

#### Locally (cloned project)

Once you clone the repository again all is locally on your device.
Every change is committed locally to your local repository.

**Disconnecting remote repo***
If you wish to disconnect your remote repository you simply need to remove the origin `git remote rm <name>`

**Adding additional remote repositories***

```
git remote add <name1> <url1>
git remote add <name2> <url2>
```

Now you can choose to which remote to push to

---

[image]

Comment: Hi codeWizad,
Thanks for your answer but when you write:
« When you start project locally its all local ofcourse…. »
This is exactly the opposite that I want to do.
I have a project that exits ALREADY on the Remote server and I have nothing in local.

1/ How can i git-pull this existant project (like if i do it with ftp)  so i can make changes in local

 When i finish my changes in local:
2/How could I do to make the changes directly reflected on the production site (with git hooks for example or something else).

Remember, we start from nothing in local, the project ONLY exist in « «remote »

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with a copy without impacting your remote repository. You must delete the reference to your remote repository with the command:

`$git remote rm remote_repositories_name`

For a list of the remote repository, use that command:

`$git remote -v`

Example:

`$git remote -v`

Résult:

```
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Remove remote

`$git remote rm origin`

Answer (score 0):

You should make a centralize git repository with the existing project and  clone the existing project on your production server and workstation locally from the centralize repository using "git clone".

When you will edit files locally and push the changes, your changes will not be affect directly on the online production site. You will need to pull your changes on the online production site form git repository.

[See the workflow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey5j6.png)